# Unable to cast when using reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

Following Coobird's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606344/dlls-for-a-dynamic-java-program) yesterday, I'm having trouble getting reflection to work in Java. I'll post the classes first then go into detail.

StHandler.java

```
package ds; public interface StHandler {
public void read();
}
```

DiStHandler.java

```
package ds;
public class DiStHandler {
public void read() {
System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

Server.java

```
package ds;
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("ds.DiStHandler");
StHandler input = (StHandler) clazz.newInstance();
input.read();
}
catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

What I am trying to do: I have an interface StHandler, which at the moment I want to have a single method: read(). DiStHandler is an implementation class which is available from the classpath. I'm trying to call the read method from here.

The problem: On the line

```
StHandler input = (StHandler) clazz.newInstance();
```

I am receiving the error: `ds.DiStHandler cannot be cast to ds.StHandler`

I have been trying to debug this for nearly two hours now but for the life of me cannot work out what the problem is. The reason I don't have `implements StHandler` in DiStHandler is because I'm creating DiStHandler in a separate project.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this.
Thanks very much in advance,

M

Answer (score 8):

You can't cast `DiStHandler` to `StHandler` if `DiStHandler` doesn't implement that interface. Reflection doesn't let you subvert the type system - everything must still be type-safe.

If `DiStHandler` can't implement `StHandler`, then you need something else which does, and which in turn calls `DiStHandler` (i.e. an adapter class).

Comment: Mm I thought so - I wonder: what if I were to put my interface class StHandler in the same project as DiStHandler and had DiStHandler implementing, compile, then just take the DiStHandler.class from the resulting files? Thank you very much for the replies. :)

Comment: Probably..I'll give it a go now, I'm up against a code deadline so I'm looking for a fast way to implement API functionality so would be very interested in seeing if this works. If not then I'll try an adapter class. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You write

> The reason I don't have

DiStHandler implements StHandler

> is because
>   I'm creating DiStHandler in a separate
>   project.

Even if `StHandler` is in a different project you can still use this construct. Indeed it may be good design to split projects. If so you should look at tools such as maven for managing dependencies - your DiStHandler will *depend* on StHandler . Getting maven into your tool chain will pay back quickly in terms of modularity